# XSSF POI is cell date

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

Is there a way to determine if cell is a date?
I know about style.getDataFormatString() but that doesn't help me,
because I can't determine if is formating is for date or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using the XSSF UserModel, then you want [DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell)) - this will return a boolean telling you if the format string for the cell represents a data or not.

If you're down at the low level XML stuff, you need [DateUtil.isADateFormat(int,String)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isADateFormat(int,%20java.lang.String)) instead. The style ID comes from the cell xml. The style string you'll have to get out of the styles table, which is a different Package Part. There are helpers for loading that though

You probably want to look at [XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator from Tika](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ooxml/XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator.java) for an example of doing the latter - it does formatting of cells from an event parsing.

Comment: I'm actually copy/paste http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200905.mbox/%3C4A0B1DC5.3070803@invest-faq.com%3E and try to modify it. Yes I did see that possibility but don't know how to retrieve Cell.

Comment: Are you using XSSF usermodel, or doing event model raw XML stuff?

Answer (score 4):

cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC && DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)

Comment: Why are you checking if the CellType is Numeric if the question is related to Date cell?

Comment: when you use DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell), but the CellType is String, it will appear "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell" @araknoid

Comment: You should add this details to the answer and explain it a bit because as it is written, It's not a self-explaining answer