# HSSF POI : How to know if data in cell is of Type Date?

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

Currently i have my code as

```
bean.setREPO_DATE(row.getCell(16).getDateCellValue());
```

it works fine if cell is formatted as date in excel.

However it also converts some integer or long like 1234 or 5699 to date. I know the reason behind this too.

However i want to apply a check before executing above line. Something like this

```
if(row.getCell(16).isOfDateFormat){
bean.setREPO_DATE(row.getCell(16).getDateCellValue());
}
```

Please Guide me..

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSSF POI is cell date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677326/xssf-poi-is-cell-date)

Comment: Sorry for that i have actually searched for it before posting the question

Comment: @ Abhishek Singh : it was not exactly a duplicate(though you could the api in that answer. I removed my close vote)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this,

use `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;`

```
if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
   {
       cell.getDateCellValue();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks its working for me. can u please tell me how to check whether the value in cell is in percentage or normal number?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell if cell type is String

Comment: You need to check if it's numeric before you check it is date. The only way for you to tell if a number is a date or a number is to look at its style. But you have to make sure it's a number first.From an answer to my similar [question]. Author: RealSkeptic. (stackoverflow.com/questions/60155480/…) . Someone can edit this so the word "question" points to my question. @SeSong